# How to Install playwright dependency in elastic beanstalk .ebextensions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, playwright

I need to download playwright dependency in my Elastic beanstalk. So, I am using this command in .ebextensions

`.ebextensions/01_install_playwright.config`

```
container_commands:
  install_playwright: 
    command: "npx playwright install --with-deps chromium"
```

But it's getting error out. Here are the logs from `cfn-init.log` -

```
2022-09-29 05:16:17,188 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2022-09-29 05:16:17,194 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2022-09-29 05:16:17,197 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2022-09-29 05:16:17,200 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_test_worker
2022-09-29 05:16:18,246 [ERROR] Command install_playwright (npx playwright install --with-deps chromium) failed
2022-09-29 05:16:18,246 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_test_worker: Command install_playwright failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 576, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 276, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command install_playwright failed
2022-09-29 05:16:18,247 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2022-09-29 05:16:18,247 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command install_playwright failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 564, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 576, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 276, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command install_playwright failed
```

Am I missing something or any suggestion on how to run the `npx` command on `.ebextensions`.

The reason I am doing this is because of invalid character in Chinese language website screenshot and [installing dependency is recommended](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/15146) in this thread for Amazon Linux, Ubuntu etc.

I also tried to SSH into EB to install manually, but that’s also failing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Playwright, but see it has a chromium dependency and you are using AWS Beanstalk. Chromium needs a few extra libraries to install correctly.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chimmelb/6342504893b2b9fce0f4a8efd096ae60). It becomes an easier script if you are using AWS Linux 2, but past revisions of the script were for Linux1 (likely out of date at this point). In you SSH session there is an error about not having `apt-get`, and the Linux2 version of the script is handled solely with `yum`. This gist was created for Puppeteer, which also needed chromium, and it was chromium that needed a bunch of extra libraries.

On other thing to note is `liberation-sans-fonts` for my project. If there is another font/language library that includes your invalid Chinese character, and maybe you can handle it that way? See the command at the bottom of the file that refreshes the font cache. That's just an idea, the chromium libs are first concern.

Comment: I am able to run the command `npx install playwright` manually when I logged in as root user. So, no issue on library. I just need to find out how to run it via `.ebextensions.`

Comment: Sorry, I thought the SSH into EB also failed to install.

Comment: Any suggestion to on running the command via .ebextensions?

Comment: I use that gist in `.ebextensions` . There is a `commands:` line which can basically run any command. Hopefully that is a useful example.

Comment: @VikashRathee I still have kind of similar question and raised the query with the log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74696909/how-to-fix-playwrightcrawler-package-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk-linux-2. Can you see if you can help please.

Comment: @clay are you able to help with my query?

Comment: @VikashRathee did you found out how to run it through `.ebextenstions`?

Comment: No, nothing worked for me