# ERROR in AWS Elastic Beanstalk for using PlaywrightCrawler package

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, playwright

When trying to use PlaywrightCrawler package in my server environment I get below error log.

```
        [32mINFO[39m [33m PlaywrightCrawler:[39m Starting the crawl
        [33mWARN[39m [33m PlaywrightCrawler:[39m Reclaiming failed request back to the list or queue. browserType.launchPersistentContext: Failed to launch: Error: spawn /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1033/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT
    
============================================================
        at async PlaywrightPlugin._launch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@crawlee/browser-pool/playwright/playwright-plugin.js:99:40)
        at async BrowserPool._launchBrowser (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@crawlee/browser-pool/browser-pool.js:465:29)
        at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/@crawlee/browser-pool/browser-pool.js:274:37[90m {"id":"erPiwuCRDH5Dzyr","url":"https://www.google.com.au/search?tbm=shop&hl=en-AU&psb=1&ved=2ahUKEwjP49q7gdb7AhUyn0sFHcYhAAQQu-kFegQIABAL&q=Coles+Extra Virgin Avocado Oil 250mL&oq=Coles+Extra Virgin Avocado Oil 250mL&gs_lcp=Cgtwcm9kdWN0cy1jYxADUABYAGAAaABwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEA&sclient=products-cc&ts=658","method":"GET","uniqueKey":"https://www.google.com.au/search?gs_lcp=Cgtwcm9kdWN0cy1jYxADUABYAGAAaABwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEA&hl=en-AU&oq=Coles+Extra Virgin Avocado Oil 250mL&psb=1&q=Coles+Extra Virgin Avocado Oil 250mL&sclient=products-cc&tbm=shop&ts=658&ved=2ahUKEwjP49q7gdb7AhUyn0sFHcYhAAQQu-kFegQIABAL"}[39m
    [32mINFO[39m [33m PlaywrightCrawler:[39m All the requests from request list and/or request queue have been processed, the crawler will shut down.
    [32mINFO[39m [33m PlaywrightCrawler:[39m Crawl finished. Final request statistics:[90m {"requestsFinished":0,"requestsFailed":1,"retryHistogram":[null,null,null,1],"requestAvgFailedDurationMillis":107,"requestAvgFinishedDurationMillis":null,"requestsFinishedPerMinute":0,"requestsFailedPerMinute":5,"requestTotalDurationMillis":107,"requestsTotal":1,"crawlerRuntimeMillis":11078}[39m
            
    [32mINFO[39m [33m PlaywrightCrawler:[39m Error analysis:[90m {"totalErrors":1,"uniqueErrors":1,"mostCommonErrors":["1x: browserType.launchPersistentContext: Failed to launch: Error: spawn /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1033/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@crawlee/browser-pool/playwright/playwright-plugin.js:99:40)"]}[39m
```

Here is my .ebextension/chromium.config:

```
packages:
  yum:
    cups-libs: []
    dbus-glib: []
    libXrandr: []
    libXcursor: []
    libXinerama: []
    cairo: []
    cairo-gobject: []
    pango: []
    libwayland-client: []
    libwayland-cursor: []
    gtk3: []
    gdk-pixbuf2: []
    libxkbcommon: []
    libXScrnSaver: []
    GConf2: []
    atk: []
    at-spi2-atk: []
    at-spi2-core: []
    alsa-lib: []

container_commands:
  install_playwright: 
    command: "npx playwright install --with-deps chromium"
```

Below is the output of my yum.log:

```
Dec 08 10:06:18 Installed: libwayland-client-1.17.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:18 Installed: mesa-libglapi-18.3.4-5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:18 Installed: atk-2.22.0-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:18 Installed: fontpackages-filesystem-1.44-8.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: 1:liberation-fonts-common-1.07.2-16.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: libusbx-1.0.21-1.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: pixman-0.34.0-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: libxshmfence-1.2-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: 1:libglvnd-1.0.1-0.1.git5baa1e5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: libwayland-server-1.17.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: mesa-libgbm-18.3.4-5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: libgusb-0.2.9-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: 1:liberation-mono-fonts-1.07.2-16.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: 1:liberation-serif-fonts-1.07.2-16.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: 1:liberation-narrow-fonts-1.07.2-16.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: 1:liberation-sans-fonts-1.07.2-16.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: 1:liberation-fonts-1.07.2-16.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: dejavu-fonts-common-2.33-6.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:19 Installed: dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-6.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:20 Installed: fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: libwayland-cursor-1.17.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: graphite2-1.3.10-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: harfbuzz-1.7.5-2.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: vulkan-filesystem-1.0.61.1-2.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: jasper-libs-1.900.1-33.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: alsa-lib-1.1.4.1-2.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: fribidi-1.0.2-1.amzn2.1.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: libepoxy-1.3.1-2.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: json-glib-1.4.2-2.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: hicolor-icon-theme-0.12-7.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: xkeyboard-config-2.20-1.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:21 Installed: libxkbcommon-0.7.1-3.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:22 Installed: dconf-0.28.0-4.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:22 Installed: gsettings-desktop-schemas-3.28.0-3.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:22 Installed: avahi-libs-0.6.31-20.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:22 Installed: 1:cups-libs-1.6.3-51.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:22 Installed: libthai-0.1.14-9.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:22 Installed: trousers-0.3.14-2.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: gnutls-3.3.29-9.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libXau-1.0.8-2.1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libxcb-1.12-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: vulkan-1.0.61.1-2.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libX11-common-1.6.7-3.amzn2.0.2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libX11-1.6.7-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libXext-1.3.3-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libXrender-0.9.10-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libXfixes-5.0.3-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libXdamage-1.1.4-4.1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libXrandr-1.5.1-2.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libXi-1.7.9-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:23 Installed: libXcomposite-0.4.4-4.1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: gdk-pixbuf2-2.36.12-3.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.22.30-3.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: libXtst-1.2.3-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: at-spi2-core-2.22.0-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: at-spi2-atk-2.22.0-2.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: libXcursor-1.1.15-1.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: libXft-2.3.2-2.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: libXinerama-1.1.3-2.1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: libXxf86vm-1.1.4-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: mesa-libGL-18.3.4-5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: 1:libglvnd-glx-1.0.1-0.1.git5baa1e5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: 1:libglvnd-egl-1.0.1-0.1.git5baa1e5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: mesa-libEGL-18.3.4-5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: cairo-1.15.12-4.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: pango-1.42.4-4.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: cairo-gobject-1.15.12-4.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: libwayland-egl-1.17.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: 1:emacs-filesystem-27.2-4.amzn2.0.1.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:24 Installed: desktop-file-utils-0.23-2.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:25 Installed: xdg-utils-1.1.0-0.17.20120809git.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:25 Installed: lcms2-2.6-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:25 Installed: colord-libs-1.3.4-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:25 Installed: adwaita-cursor-theme-3.26.0-1.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:28 Installed: adwaita-icon-theme-3.26.0-1.amzn2.noarch
Dec 08 10:06:28 Installed: libmodman-2.0.1-8.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:28 Installed: libproxy-0.4.11-10.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:28 Installed: glib-networking-2.56.1-1.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:28 Installed: libsoup-2.56.0-6.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:28 Installed: rest-0.8.0-2.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:29 Installed: gtk3-3.22.30-3.amzn2.x86_64
Dec 08 10:06:43 Installed: google-chrome-stable-108.0.5359.98-1.x86_64
```

Even all the chromium dependencies has been installed, still getting the issue.

There is no such issue when running it locally.

Hope someone can advise what is the issue.

---

UPDATE:

After further research found that the issue could be with the Docker image. So I replaced my existing Docker image with `[zenika/alpine-chrome:with-playwright][1]` which has playwright and headless chrome and included a new RUN command for `npx playwright install`. Now getting a new error which is:

```
[31mERROR[39m[33m PlaywrightCrawler:[39m Request failed and reached maximum retries. browserType.launchPersistentContext: Executable doesn't exist at /home/chrome/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1028/chrome-linux/chrome
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
║                                                                         ║
║     npx playwright install                                              ║
║                                                                         ║
║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
    at async PlaywrightPlugin._launch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/crawlee/node_modules/@crawlee/playwright/node_modules/@crawlee/browser-pool/playwright/playwright-plugin.js:99:40)
    at async BrowserPool._launchBrowser (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@crawlee/browser/node_modules/@crawlee/browser-pool/browser-pool.js:465:29)
    at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/@crawlee/browser/node_modules/@crawlee/browser-pool/browser-pool.js:274:37[90m {"id":"tGOZOvUIBmhYpXW","url":"https://www.google.com.au/search?tbm=shop&hl=en-AU&psb=1&ved=2ahUKEwjP49q7gdb7AhUyn0sFHcYhAAQQu-kFegQIABAL&q=Coles+Extra Virgin Avocado Oil 250mL&oq=Coles+Extra Virgin Avocado Oil 250mL&gs_lcp=Cgtwcm9kdWN0cy1jYxADUABYAGAAaABwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEA&sclient=products-cc&ts=782","method":"GET","uniqueKey":"https://www.google.com.au/search?gs_lcp=Cgtwcm9kdWN0cy1jYxADUABYAGAAaABwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEA&hl=en-AU&oq=Coles+Extra Virgin Avocado Oil 250mL&psb=1&q=Coles+Extra Virgin Avocado Oil 250mL&sclient=products-cc&tbm=shop&ts=782&ved=2ahUKEwjP49q7gdb7AhUyn0sFHcYhAAQQu-kFegQIABAL"}[39m
[32mINFO[39m [33m PlaywrightCrawler:[39m All the requests from request list and/or request queue have been processed, the crawler will shut down.
[32mINFO[39m [33m PlaywrightCrawler:[39m Crawl finished. Final request statistics:[90m {"requestsFinished":0,"requestsFailed":1,"retryHistogram":[null,null,null,1],"requestAvgFailedDurationMillis":18,"requestAvgFinishedDurationMillis":null,"requestsFinishedPerMinute":0,"requestsFailedPerMinute":5,"requestTotalDurationMillis":18,"requestsTotal":1,"crawlerRuntimeMillis":11089}[39m
[32mINFO[39m [33m PlaywrightCrawler:[39m Error analysis:[90m {"totalErrors":1,"uniqueErrors":1,"mostCommonErrors":["1x: browserType.launchPersistentContext: Executable doesn't exist at /home/chrome/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1028/chrome-linux/chrome (/usr/src/app/node_modules/crawlee/node_modules/@crawlee/playwright/node_modules/@crawlee/browser-pool/playwright/playwright-plugin.js:99:40)"]}[39m
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# # This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
FROM zenika/alpine-chrome:with-playwright

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PORT 3000

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install --force
RUN npx playwright install

COPY . /usr/src/app

# replace this with your application's default port
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Elastic-Beanstalk does some magic with current and staging applications running at the same time. As far as I can tell deployment of a new Version is done in a container. This means installations of dependencies like chrome will not work with an absolute directory (like /root/.cache) - the fix I used was to configure a relative directory (in puppeteer via `.puppeteerrc.cjs` -- `cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),` then the chrome download will be in the local directory for each version.

Comment: The error looks like chromium is not installed, but playwright exists. It does look like the chromium libraries are loading, but I don't know if that `npx playwright` command will work. `npx playwight` will execute playwright's install command then and there (if node and npm even work from that script). I use puppeteer and install via package.json in the project file. If I want a global command, I would use something other than npm. Maybe you can use yum to install a chromium that playwright can use? good luck, I hope you figure it out.

Comment: @Falco I have even tried to change my Docker image and use an image which has playwright and headless chrome installed and included Docker RUN command for '''npx playwright install''', but still doesn't work. Please see the update section of the question for the new log. Any clue what could be the issue?

Comment: According to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html AWS will launch a container, perform the build, copy the sourcecode out of the container and then destroy the container. `You can use the container_commands key to execute commands that affect your application source code.` An installation in the container Command will only work, if the target directory is your local source-code directory.

Comment: Two possible solutions: 1. specify your local directory for playwright `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=./.cache/playwright` or solution 2. Use `commands` instead of `container_commands` and install playwright to a global directory for all users together with: `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=/root/.cache/playwright`

Comment: @clay I've used a global command to install chrome beforehand via `wget ...chrome-isntallation.rpm && sudo yum install chrome...local.prm` this will also install all dependencies via yum. After that puppeteer can either use the global installed chrome, or install its own into a local directory. I used a local directory `./.cache` so puppeteer can install a compatible version, just to be safe.

Comment: @Falco, I have tried to use the commands to install "npx playwright install" in this directory "/root/.cache/playwright" and getting the same issue as above. 

I have also tried to use the official Docker image "[FROM apify/actor-node-playwright-chrome:16](https://crawlee.dev/docs/guides/docker-images#actor-node-playwright-chrome)" for Playwright from Crawlee with their default Dockerfile but getting the same error. There is an open issue about it in [GitHub](https://github.com/apify/apify-actor-docker/issues/87), but no one in the repo giving any solution :(

Comment: Also regarding chromium dep, all of them has been installed. You can see it from my yum.log file.

Comment: @Falco, this is my updated EB config:

commands:
  npx playwright install: 
    command: "npx playwright install"
    env:
      PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH = "/root/.cache/playwright"
    cwd: env.PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH

Comment: this should be working, or what are the errors now ?

Comment: @Falco - the error is still the same -> Executable doesn't exist at /home/chrome/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1028/chrome-linux/chrome

Comment: Any clue regarding granting permission in the container for accessing that path?

Comment: @ShahryarFaraji you also have to provide PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH  environment variable to your webserver process, because it needs to now where chrome is installed. The error message looks like it is still searching for chrome under the old path. - so currently you are correctly installing playwright to `/root/.cache` but nodejs looks for it under `/home/chrome` - also put the environment variable into your startup script or node-environment file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALL FIXED.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
# Get the base image of Node version 16
FROM node:16

# Get the latest version of Playwright
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal

# Set the work directory for the application
WORKDIR /app

# COPY the needed files to the app folder in Docker image
COPY package*.json /app/

# Get the needed libraries to run Playwright
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libdrm-dev libxkbcommon-dev libgbm-dev libasound-dev libatspi2.0-0 libxshmfence-dev

# Install the dependencies in Node environment
RUN npm ci

# Start the main script
CMD ["node", "--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229", "src/main.js"]
```

Here is the EB config

```
container:
  install_playwright: 
    command: PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=$HOME/pw-browsers npx playwright install
```